# one large sql server table of several smaller ones?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, scalability

I have some design question to ask.

Suppose I'm having some `TBL_SESSIONS` table where I keep every logged-in `user-id` and some `Dirty-flag` (indicating whether the content he has was changed since he got it).

Now, this table should be periodically be asked every few seconds by any signed-in user about that `Dirty-flag`, i.e., there are a lot of read calls on that table, and also this `Dirty-flag` is changed a lot.

Suppose I'm expecting many users to be logged in at the same time. I was wondering if there is any reason in creating like say 10 such tables and have the users distributed (say according their user-ids) between those table.

I'm asking this from two aspects. First, in terms of performance. Second, in terms of scalability.

I would love to hear your opinions

Comment: Please define "llarge". How many billion rows? Because anything below 100 million or so should be a total non-issue (except you believing that this is alrge data - which many developers sadly do). 25 years ago, 1 million rows was large, Today this is tiny.

Comment: let's say 1 million rows (that's mean 1 million users are logged-in)

Comment: oops.. I didn't get your full message before answering. So, are you saying that a table of 1 million rows where every row is being at least read every few seconds is not an issue?

Comment: No, not at all. Not when done properly, not when some caching is used.

Comment: That is very good news to me. Thank you - TomTom, Tony, and Sergio for your answers. I'll accept Sergio's answer because it gave me some food for thoughts about scalability as well. Again, thank you all.

Comment: You can't make any performance-related decision without having an *actual performance target* in mind, and you haven't given nearly enough information for anyone to provide a well considered answer. What is an acceptable duration for reading a record? How many simultaneously active users are you expecting (which affects the chances of caching data)? What rate of new records are you expecting? Are new users likely to be more active than old users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having several tables makes sence if you have really lots of records in it, like billions, and high load that your server cannot handle. This way you can perform **sharding** -> split one table to several on **different** servers. E.g. have first 100 millions of records on server `A` (id 1 to 100 000 000), next 100 million on server `B` (100 000 001 to 200 000 000) etc.  Other way - is having **same** data on **different** and querying data through some kind of balancer, wich may be harder (replication isn't key feature of RDBMS, so it depends on engine)

Comment: In your example sharding plan, you're putting all of the new user load onto a single shard. That doesn't really sound like a good plan.

Answer (score 1):

For 1m rows use a single table.

With correct indexing the access time should not be a problem. If you use multiple tables with users distributed across them you will have additional processing necessary to find which table to read/update.

Also, how many users will you allocate to each table? And what happens when the number of users grows... add more tables? I think you'll end up with a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: This should certainly be the default approach in the absence of much more information.